# go-flags: panic: provided data is not a pointer to struct

Tags: go

I'm trying to modify some go code that uses this package: https://godoc.org/github.com/jessevdk/go-flags

The program compiles and runs fine if I try to run it with no args, but if I try using any args I get a panic message "provided data is not a pointer to struct" followed by a stack trace. I'm new to this and I'm not sure what I'm overlooking...

The error message seems to point to this block:

```
func (c *NsOpts) Execute(args []string) error {
    if err != nil {
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    checkCert(c.Username, c.Password, c.Address)
    return nil
}
```

This is the NsOpts struct:

```
//DiskOpts contains the plugin options
type NsOpts struct {
    Username string `short:"u" long:"username" description:"Username for the netscaler" required:"true"`
    Password string `short:"p" long:"password" description:"Password for the netscaler" required:"true"`
    Address  string `short:"a" long:"address" description:"FQDN or IP to connect to" required:"true"`
}

var nsOpts NsOpts

//teling go-flags to add this plugin as an available command
func init() {
    parser.AddCommand("check-netscaler", "Checks netscaler certificates expiration", "Checks netscaler certs", &nsOpts)
}
```

And this is the func being called:

```
func checkCert(username, password, host string) {
...
}
```

Comment: Please post your error message and stack trace

Comment: Btw, how does your `Execute` function even compile, what does the if check do? What is the `err` in that place, some package variable?